# Ruby on Rails - Ruby, How to add the values from two hashes with same key, without overwriting the values?

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

first of all thank you for helping me with my SQL question, at this point.

Now I'm struggling with another thing, makes me think if I should quit being a programmer to be honest.

Anyway, my problem is : I have an array of hashes( and inside that hash another ) like this:

```
[
 {"A1"=>{:month=>1.0, :balance=>"0.0000", :price=>"9.0000"}}, 
 {"A1"=>{:month=>7.0, :balance=>"34030.0000", :price=>"34030.0000"}},
 {"A3"=>{:month=>4.0, :balance=>"34030.0000", :price=>"34030.0000"}},
 ...
]
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is that, if there are two values with the same key, ie "A1" add those values into one whole hash, without overwriting the old values and having the month as a key desired output:

```
[
 {"A1"=> { 1 => { :balance=> "0.0000", :price=>"9.0000"} },
         { 7 => { :balance => "34030.0000", :price => "34030.0000" } }},
  and so on... 
]
```

Is this posible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due the current format of the data you have, you'll need more than a couple of transformations. Most of them based on transforming the values of the resulting hash, after grouping the hashes in the array by their only key:

```
data
  .group_by { |hash| hash.keys.first }                                     # (1)
  .transform_values { |value| value.flat_map(&:values) }                   # (2)
  .transform_values { |values| values.index_by { |value| value[:month] } } # (3)
```

The first transformation is to group the current object, holding an array of hashes, by its only hash key, hence the `keys.first`, resulting in:

```
{
  "A1"=>[
    {"A1"=>{:month=>1.0, :balance=>"0.0000", :price=>"9.0000"}}, 
    {"A1"=>{:month=>7.0, :balance=>"34030.0000", :price=>"34030.0000"}}
  ],
  "A3"=>[{"A3"=>{:month=>4.0, :balance=>"34030.0000", :price=>"34030.0000"}}]
}
```

The second, is to extract only the values from each hash, in the resulting hash, with arrays of hashes:

```
{
  "A1"=>[
    {:month=>1.0, :balance=>"0.0000", :price=>"9.0000"}, 
    {:month=>7.0, :balance=>"34030.0000", :price=>"34030.0000"}
  ],
  "A3"=>[{:month=>4.0, :balance=>"34030.0000", :price=>"34030.0000"}]
}
```

Then, it just lacks to transform the array of hashes, to simply an hash, whose keys are the value of `month`:

```
{
  "A1"=>{
    1.0=>{:month=>1.0, :balance=>"0.0000", :price=>"9.0000"}, 
    7.0=>{:month=>7.0, :balance=>"34030.0000", :price=>"34030.0000"}
  },
  "A3"=>{4.0=>{:month=>4.0, :balance=>"34030.0000", :price=>"34030.0000"}}
}
```

Comment: Thank you so so much for your help, tried +1 but I don't have the reputation, it helped me a lot

Comment: Don't worry about the rep. If the answer solved your problem, then accepting it is enough ;)

Answer (score 3):

@Sebastian's answer is excellent. For variety, let's also consider an iterative approach. Not sure if it's more efficient or easier to understand, but it's always good to understand multiple perspectives.

Setting up the input data you gave us:

```
arr = [
 {"A1"=>{:month=>1.0, :balance=>"0.0000", :price=>"9.0000"}}, 
 {"A1"=>{:month=>7.0, :balance=>"34030.0000", :price=>"34030.0000"}},
 {"A3"=>{:month=>4.0, :balance=>"34030.0000", :price=>"34030.0000"}}]
```

We create a new empty hash for our results.

```
new_hash = {}
```

And now iterating over the original data. We're going to make some assumptions about the form of the data.

```
# We know each thing is going to be a hash.
arr.each do |hsh|
    # Set up some convenient variables for keys and 
    # values we'll need later.
    key = hsh.keys.first
    value = hsh.values.first
    month = value[:month]
    
    # If the output hash doesn't yet have the key,
    # give it the key and assign an empty hash to it.
    new_hash[key] ||= {}
    # Assign the value to the hash, keyed to the current month.
    new_hash[key][month] = value
    # ... and get rid of the month key that's now redundant.
    new_hash[key][month].delete(:month)
end
```

And the result is:

```
{"A1"=>{1.0=>{:balance=>"0.0000", :price=>"9.0000"}, 
        7.0=>{:balance=>"34030.0000", :price=>"34030.0000"}}, 
 "A3"=>{4.0=>{:balance=>"34030.0000", :price=>"34030.0000"}}}
```

Comment: This is a nice approach, because you get access to what you really need within the `each` block, because as you can see I didn't remove the `month` key/value pairs. But it has the counterpart to blind people with big blocks of code while they could be chunk into transformations that can be plugged in for easy debugging.

Comment: Thank you so much both for your great answers, this is my first job as a dev and I know I have too much to learn, I really appreciate it, if I could help with anything just let me know.

Comment: I think the virtues of this approach vs. the more functional approach in the previous answer will likely scale with the size of the dataset being used. Each transformation on these data structures takes time. On a small dataset, the difference is negligible. There is also the complexity of the transformation. Of course, as complexity of this goes up, it's likely the best answer is not to just use hashes and arrays, but to wrap that data up into your own class, and use meaningful method names to identify what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Arguably it would be more useful for the desired return value to be a hash:

```
h = {"A1"=>{1=>{:balance=>    "0.0000", :price=>    "9.0000"},
            7=>{:balance=>"34030.0000", :price=>"34030.0000"}},
     "A3"=>{4=>{:balance=>"34030.0000", :price=>"34030.0000"}}}
```

That way you could write, for example:

```
require 'bigdecimal'

BigDecimal(h['A1'][7][:price]) 
  #=> 0.3403e5
```

See [BigDecimal](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html). `BigDecimal` is generally used in financial calculations because it avoids round-off errors.

This result can be obtained by changing the values of `:month` to integers in `arr`:

```
arr = [
  {"A1"=>{:month=>1, :balance=>    "0.0000", :price=>    "9.0000"}}, 
  {"A1"=>{:month=>7, :balance=>"34030.0000", :price=>"34030.0000"}},
  {"A3"=>{:month=>4, :balance=>"34030.0000", :price=>"34030.0000"}}
]
```

and by computing:

```
h = arr.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  k,v = g.flatten
  (h[k] ||= {}).update(v[:month]=>v.reject { |k,_| k == :month })
end
```

See [Hash#flatten](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-flatten), [Hash#update](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) and [Hash#reject](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-reject).

One could alternatively write:

```
h = arr.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = {} }) do |g,h|
  k,v = g.flatten
  h[k].update(v[:month]=>v.reject { |k,_| k == :month })
end
```

See the form of [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) that takes a block.